# notifyItemRangeInserted not refresh 0 items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have `RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>` with pagination button(Load More)

Load More button in RecyclerView like Footer. Each request get 20 rows and if I get <20 items I need disable this button:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof ViewHolder) {
            ...
        } else if (holder instanceof FooterViewHolder) {
            ...
            viewHolder.loadMore.setEnabled(isVisibleLoadButton);
        }
    }

public void addData(List<TransactionItem> opcTransactions) {
        final int positionStart = transactionItems.size()+1;
        isVisibleLoadButton = opcTransactions.size() >= 20;
        transactionItems.addAll(opcTransactions);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart, opcTransactions.size());
    }
```

If I get `opcTransactions` with 1 or more items `isVisibleLoadButton`  set false and my load More button set disable. But If I get emty list `opcTransactions` size = 0 - load More button not diasbled.

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (transactionItems == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (transactionItems.size() == 0) {
            //Return 1 here to show nothing
            return 1;
        }

        // Add extra view to show the footer view
        return transactionItems.size() + 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in this line .

```
final int positionStart = transactionItems.size()+1;
```

positionStart should point to last item of your list . and indexing starts form **ZERO**. Use it as .

```
final int positionStart = transactionItems.size();
```

Comment: not. I use this specially. if I add +1 - when I load first 20 items my list not scroled to buttom (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30455749/4781349) and if I not use +1 button not disabled too

Comment: Whats the point of +1? when you are ultimately calling `notifyItemRangeInserted` not `notifyItemChanged` .

Comment: I do not understand you. I wrote a link with the answer why I use +1. and clarified that even if I do not use +1, it still does not work